# Memory Allocation in SystemVerilog Class

Tags: oop, system-verilog

Is there any system task or function available in SV to know, how much memory is allocated to an object of a class?

Regards,
H.Modh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SystemVerilog manages memory automatically and you are not supposed to be aware of the memory resources for any kind of object. That said, most tool vendors provide capacity reports that can tell you how much memory different categories of constructs are taking as well as the number of objects created for each class type.

Comment: Hi Dave, Tudor,
Thanks for your reply.
But, Would the knowledge of a memory allocated to an object not improve the coding style? Or we can say, would it not help to enhance the performance of a large testbench?

Comment: Profiling your code will help you write better code, but profiling is not part of the standard language - it is tool vendor specific.

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog isn't the kind of language where you need to know how much memory is allocated for an object of a class, since you can't perform any low  level memory operations by yourself. This gives freedom to simulation vendors to implement whatever they want under the hood (e.g. the tool from vendor A could use more physical memory than the one from vendor B and maybe be faster).